# Scanner code that produces an error message instead of crashing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need this code to produce an error message when the user tries to input a string instead of an int. How would I go about doing that?

> ```
>   import java.util.Scanner;
>     public class Testing {
>       public static void main (String [] args){
>         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
>         System.out.println("Please enter an int");
>         input = s.nextInt();
>
>
>
>
>
>
>       }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop. Check if there is an `int`. And if there isn't display a message. Something like,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an int");
    if (s.hasNextInt()) {
        input = s.nextInt();
        // ...
        break;
    }
    System.err.printf("%s isn't an int%n", s.next());
}
```

Comment: Since you `break` in the `if` block, there's no need for an `else` block. Just print the error (to `System.out`) after the `if` statement.

Comment: @Andreas Fair enough. Edited. Also, switched it to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if user provided proper `int` with `hasNextInt()` method.

- if validation was OK read that value with `nextInt()`.
- if value was not `int` you can use `next()` to consume it (you don't have to really use that value, but you need to take it out from scanner so you could read other values from user).